# Creating a dataframe in GeoPandas gives "TypeError super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, shapely

`TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type` when creating 1 column for points from 2 columns lat and long

Could you please help me with this?

I have a data set as 
customer_lat, customer_lng
I want to create 1 column as a point from lat long

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\n.nguyen.2\\Documents\\order from May 1.csv")

geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['customer_lat'],df['customer_lng'])]
crs={'init':'epsg:4326'}
gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs=crs,geometry=geometry)
gdf.head()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-82-1f38d31ae996>", line 9, in <module>
    gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs=crs,geometry=geometry)

  File "C:\Users\n.nguyen.2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 47, in __init__
    super(GeoDataFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: I assume you have resolved it? (based on your next questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413817/define-points-within-a-polygon). Can you share what was the issue?

Comment: Hi, it does not work in Spyder but it works in Jupyter Notebook.